# pandas: replace values in column with the last character in the column name

Tags: python, pandas, replace, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'sent.1':[0,1,0,1],
                'sent.2':[0,1,1,0],
                'sent.3':[0,0,0,1],
                'sent.4':[1,1,0,1]
               })
```

I am trying to replace the non-zero values with the 5th character in the column names (which is the numeric part of the column names), so the output should be,

```
   sent.1  sent.2  sent.3  sent.4
0       0       0       0       4
1       1       2       0       4
2       0       2       0       0
3       1       0       3       4
```

I have tried the following but it does not work,

```
print(df.replace(1, pd.Series([i[5] for i in df.columns], [i[5] for i in df.columns])))
```

However when I replace it with column name, the above code works, so I am not sure which part is wrong.

```
print(df.replace(1, pd.Series(df.columns,  df.columns)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're dealing with 1's and 0's, you can actually just use multiply the dataframe by a range:

```
df = df * range(1, df.shape[1] + 1)
```

Output:

```
   sent.1  sent.2  sent.3  sent.4
0       0       0       0       4
1       1       2       0       4
2       0       2       0       0
3       1       0       3       4
```

Or, if you want to take the numbers from the column names:

```
df = df * df.columns.str.split('.').str[-1].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use string multiplication on a boolean array to place the strings based on the condition, and `where` to restore the zeros:

```py
mask = df.ne(0)
(mask*df.columns.str[5]).where(mask, 0)
```

To have integers:

```py
mask = df.ne(0)
(mask*df.columns.str[5].astype(int))
```

output:

```
  sent.1 sent.2 sent.3 sent.4
0      0      0      0      4
1      1      2      0      4
2      0      2      0      0
3      1      0      3      4
```

Comment: `df.columns.str[5]` wouldn't work for double-digit numbers, e.g. `sent.10`. Maybe you should do `df.columns.str[5:]`

Comment: @richardec I followed OP's instructions "*with the 5th character*", otherwise I would have used a regex or split ;)

Answer (score 1):

And another one, working with an arbitrary condition (here `s.ne(0)`):

```
df.apply(lambda s: s.mask(s.ne(0), s.name.rpartition('.')[-1]))
```